# Do 2 Kings and 2 Chronicles contradict each other on Jehoiachin's age when taking the throne and duration of reign?

Tags: contradiction, 2-kings, 2-chronicles

In [Kings II 24:8](http://biblehub.com/2_kings/24-8.htm) it is said that Jehoiachin was 18 when he ascended the 
   throne and he reigned for 3 months. But in [Chronicles II 36:9](http://biblehub.com/2_chronicles/36-9.htm) it is 
   said that he reigned for 3 months and **10 days**. Also in the King James 
   version it is said that Jehoiachin was **8** when he ascended the throne, not 18.

Aren't the two verses contradicting each other?

Comment: 3 months vs. 3 months and 10 days is no contradiction. If I asked you how old you were, you probably wouldn't say "25 years, 147 days, 9 hours, and 53 minutes." The question regarding the age of Jehoiachin when beginning his reign is interesting, however. I suspect that Jehoiachin became king and ruled jointly with his father (in more of a de jure way) when he was 8, but that he began to rule by himself and in a de facto way when he was 18. Let's see what the answers say.

Comment: Confirmed that the Hebrew for the Kings passage has 18 and for the Chronicles passage 8. One is tempted to see the missing 10 (which in "eighteen" is a separate word in Hebrew — "eight ten") reappearing as the unexpected number of days...

Comment: What form of mathematics is involved?  Algebra, Geometry, Calculus, Differential Equations, I don't think so.

Comment: This link is to two very competent explanations of the apparent disparity ---> [LINK](http://brandplucked.webs.com/jehoiachin8or18.htm). I don't feel the need to answer the question myself, but someone else might use the link to formulate a brief synopsis as an answer. Question up-voted as it is a valid point that requires an explanation (+1).

Comment: To explain my previous comment mathematical was replaced by numerical.

Comment: @PerryWebb alrighty

Comment: @Abu Sorry, I've been an engineer for 30 years and have teaching certification in physics and mathematics.

Comment: The [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) has *eighteen* in both places. The discrepancy seems only to exist in the [Masoretic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a contradiction but Hebrew poetry.

The logic may be compared to the anointing of David. Spiritually David became king the moment Samuel anointed David and the Spirit of the Lord departed from king Saul. Nevertheless David had to wait 15 years from the time he was first anointed by Samuel to the time he became king over Judah and another seven years before David was anointed king over all of Israel.

It is the same here:

> Commentators on 2 Kings 24:8 and 2 Chronicles 36:9 explain that Jehoiachin was, in fact, crowned twice. Shortly after Jehoiachin’s father, Jehoiakim, began his reign, he (or the king of Egypt) crowned his eight-year-old son as heir to the throne, to ensure that Jehoiachin would become king after him. See [Jehoahaz and Joiakim](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/464341/jewish/Jehoahaz-and-Joiakim.htm) and [Jehoiachin](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/464342/jewish/Jehoiachin.htm).

Peace

Answer (score 0):

2 Kings 24:12 says that Jehoiachin was taken in the eighth year of His reign, so, when he was positionally made king, by title, with his father Jehoiakim, he had to have been ten years old not eight.  The eight years old refers to how long Jehoiachin had been a positional titled king as for eight years - before he became a fully functional king after His father King Jehoiakim died, and Jehoiachin’s personal age was 18 years old when this occurred.